# how to create a destructor in es6

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, ecmascript-6

For example:

```js
function a() {
    this.heartbeat = setInterval(()=>{}, 10000)
}

var b = new a()
delete b //The heartbeat still seems to be working
```

I want to remove the heartbeat when my object is deleted.

Comment: use `clearInterval` - oh, right, you want to detect the `delete` - I think you'll need to handle it like `clearInterval(b.heartbeat); delete b;` - there's no "destructor" equivalent to c++ in javascript that I know of - also, calling `delete b` as per your example does not delete anything ... delete deletes a property of an object, b is not a property of an object - `console.log(delete b)` outputs `false` so it "failed"

Comment: read about delete ... *The JavaScript delete operator removes a property from an object; **if no more references to the same property are held**, it is eventually released automatically.* - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete ... in fact, if you were in strict mode, the code you posted would thrown an error

Comment: [Objects are not `delete`d](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there's no "built-in" destructor method of class in JavaScript, you can implement one for yourself (I'm sure that there's more options, but that's the only way I can think of):

```js
class A {
  heartbeat = setInterval(() => console.log('hearbeat'), 1000);

  destroy() {
    clearInterval(this.heartbeat);
  }
}

let a = new A();

setTimeout(() => a.destroy(), 5000);
```